# Row Removal if value on B Colum is "XYZ" or Empty on this function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function ABCDEF() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var ds=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var simDataList=['A4:AL428'];
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<simDataList.length;i++) {
    var vA=s.getRange(simDataList[i]).getValues();//get data from each range  
    for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
      oA.push(vA[j]);//append each row to output array
    }
  }
  ds.getRange(ds.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```

Function works but I need to trim the data, Sheet 1 should not change.

Is there a way to remove ALL rows if column B has string value of "XYZ" or an EMPTY value,  WHEN the function triggers/paste it on Sheet2. Again, Sheet 1 should not be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- By modifying your showing script, you want to remove the rows from the array `oA`, when column "B" includes the values of "XYZ" or the column "B" is empty.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
oA.push(vA[j]);//append each row to output array
```

#### To:

```
if (vA[j][1].includes("XYZ") || vA[j][1].toString() == "") continue;
oA.push(vA[j]);//append each row to output array
```

- By this, when column "B" includes the values of "XYZ" or the column "B" is empty, the rows are not pushed to the array `oA`.
- If you want to skip when the column "B" is "XYZ", please modify `vA[j][1].includes("XYZ")` to `vA[j][1] == "XYZ"`.

#### Reference:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: This Worked, thanks, it also removed empty spaces on B. thanks.

Comment: @DCC Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.